# Editable text docment on webpage

Tags: html

How to embed an editable text document in a webpage? Like I wanted the document itself on my webpage so that who ever opens it can write something and save it.

Comment: This is a vague request that could require html5 features, one of many possible client libraries, and/or backend services. Where will the file come from, where will it be saved? You really need to nail down what you want and then look at the specific sub problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Inline editing](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline) feature of ckeditor. or [content editable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) feature of html5

```
<section contenteditable="true">
    // Markup here
</section>
```